# how many data points one needs to estimate the nth moments of a distribution?

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, inference, moments

how many data points one needs to estimate the nth moments of a distribution ?

is there a formula for the nth moment ? also formulas for confidence interval for these parameters? Any pointer is appreciated.